# TiKZ/PGF: Rectangle with precise alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

When I import the tikzpicture below in my paper with different page size and borders the left and right lines to the rectangle get misaligned by a couple of points.

So I am puzzled to create such a diagram without absolute coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (rect) at (4,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm] {\large Rectangle};
\draw[black, thick]  (0,2.5) -- node[midway, below] {$A$} (2,2.5);
\draw[black, thick]  (0.9,2.4) -- (1.1,2.6);
\draw[black, thick]  (0,1.5) -- node[midway, below] {$B$} (2,1.5);
\draw[black, thick]  (0.9,1.4) -- (1.1,1.6);
\draw[black, thick]  (6,3.0) -- node[midway, below] {$R$} (8,3.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for help

[image]

Comment: "The left and right lines to the rectangle get misaligned by a couple of points". Do you mean their `y` coordinate? Evidently the `R` line has a `y` position of 3, so it should not align with any other line. "create such a diagram without absolute coordinates". The code you post is for a diagram based on absolute coordinates. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't see any misalignment of lines in your image. They are positioned where you say in code that had to be. Off-topic: `midway`  option in node you can omit.

Comment: I added the output from the code you posted, please edit the question to say exactly what you want to change.

Comment: The problem is when I use this picture in another document with a different paper size. But the proposed solution from Torbjørn works perfectly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library, which you load already, to calculate a position along one of the boundaries of the rectangle. For example `($(rect.north west)!0.35!(rect.south west)$)` is the point 35% of the way from the upper left to the lower left corner.

And then you can use relative coordinates to draw a line from this point, for example `++(-2,0)` is the point 2 units left of the previous active point.

To make the small line crossing the middle of the lines on the left, you can use a decoration from the `decorations.marking` library, as in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw (5pt,3pt) -- (-5pt,-3pt);}
    }]
\node (rect) at (4,2) [draw,thick,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=3cm] {\large Rectangle};
\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north west)!0.35!(rect.south west)$) -- ++(-2,0) node[midway,below] {$A$};
\draw [thick,postaction={decorate}] ($(rect.north west)!0.65!(rect.south west)$) -- ++(-2,0) node[midway,below] {$B$};
\draw [thick] ($(rect.north east)!0.3!(rect.south east)$) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,below] {$R$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Torbjørn, your proposed solution works like a charm and I learned somethin new with Tikz/PGF.  Two thumbs up!